# Multipage Dashboard Using Dash and Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a Multipage Dashboard related to cricket using Plotly and Dash in Python. I have made three separated dashboard for the followings: Teams, Venues and Players(Batsman & Bowlers). These pages contain several graphs and maps. Now, I want to connect these scripts together like what we do in HTML(using href tag linking of multiple pages). But I couldn’t find any solution regarding this. If anybody knows how to do this it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/urls) of multi page app on plotly has defined this quite well.

You can simply have an `index page` where you have code to redirect to your different apps.
Code snippet from the documentation:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    # represents the URL bar, doesn't render anything
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/"', href='/'), #Home page
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/page-2"', href='/page-2'), #App1

    # content will be rendered in this element
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])
```